# wp query to display one random post from each month in DSC order

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm trying to make this wp query to somehow return one post from each month, and to display all months from the current install. If the post is random that would be awesome. So the posts are different on each page reload.

See what I've come up with so far...

```
<?php $arhiveGrid = new WP_Query(array(

    'post_type'      => 'page'              
    'order'          => 'DESC',
    'orderby'        => 'date',
    'posts_per_page' => 99999

)); ?>

<?php if ($arhiveGrid->have_posts()) : while ($arhiveGrid->have_posts()) : $arhiveGrid->the_post();

    $retina  = wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id( $post->ID ), 'thumb-retina' ); ?>

    <a class="arhive-grid" href="<?php bloginfo('url'); the_time('/Y/m/'); ?>" style="background-image:<?php echo $retina[0]; ?>;">

        <span><?php the_time('F Y') ?></span>

    </a>

<?php endwhile; unset($arhiveGrid); endif; ?>
```

Obviously this query will return every post on my install. The code above is what I'm going to use to build my archive grid for my archives page (not archive.php).

The grid needs an image from each month as the background, with Month and Year as text overlay, and needs to link to the correct month.

But code will only work if the query above can be adapted to get a random post from each month.

Thanks for any help or pointers.

Answer (score -1):

This query will get you a random post. You can change 'numberposts' to get any number of posts

```
<?php
$args = array( 'numberposts' => 1, 'orderby' => 'rand' );
$rand_posts = get_posts( $args );
?>
```

**Edit**: If you want to get a random post from with in a time range, you have to use custom query.

```
$wpdb->query("SELECT * FROM $wpdb->posts where post_data >= '2012-03-01' AND post_data < '2012-03-31' ORDER BY RAND() limit 1 ");
```

This query will give you a random post posted in the month of March 2012.

Now you have to use this query in a loop to get random post for every month that you want.

Comment: Hello Sudar. I'm confused, will this return a random post from each month?

Comment: No, this will return one random post from the entire collection of published posts. To get one random post every month, you have to extend this.

Comment: Thanks Sudar - the extensive bit is where I get stuck, I cannot think how to do it.

Comment: I have edited the answer. Let me know if this is what you wanted.

Comment: Hi Sudar, thanks for you time - but I need it to be fully automated. It need to work like get_archives does, but retrieve a random image from a post in that month essentially